# Como ocultar o teclado no momento em que o usuário aperta um botão?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria que minha aplicação forçasse o fechamento do teclado do celular sempre que o usuário apertasse um botão (que fica acima e ao lado do edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro do click do botão, no onClickListener, coloque esse código:

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(imm.isActive())
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Isso fará com que o teclado virtual do device seja fechado.

Comment: Funcionou, mas se ao clicar no botão o teclado estiver fechado, o teclado está abrindo. Como eu posso criar um if para verificar este caso? Por exemplo apenas executar este comando se o teclado estiver aberto.

Comment: @LucasFernando, alterei o exemplo para poder colocar a condicional.

Comment: Implementei a condicional e ainda ocorre o mesmo problema

Comment: Após algumas pesquisas sobre este InputMethodManager consegui solucionar o problema alterando a linha "imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);" para "imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)"
Sinceramente não sei qual é a diferença, mas solucionou o meu problema. Se alguém souber me explicar o porque deste jeito dar certo, ou se esse é realmente a maneira correta de utilizar este código...

Answer (score 0):

Chame este método:

```
/**
 * Esconda o teclado
 */
public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if(getCurrentFocus()!=null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

/**
 * Mostre o teclado
 */
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Com base nessa excelente resposta do SOen:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977227/6736591